# SQLAlchemy hybrid_property error when setting

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pylons, getter-setter

I'm trying to use a hybrid_property decorator to define a getter/setter.  Here's the code.

```
class Users(object):
def __init__(self, username, uid=None, password=None, group_uid=None):
    self.uid = uid
    self.username = username
    self.password = password
    self.group_uid = group_uid

def __repr__(self):

    return "User(%(username)s)" % self.__dict__

@hybrid_property
def password(self):

    return self._password

@password.setter
def set_password(self, password):       

    self._password = password
```

When looking at a user object, the getter works properly, ie user.password returns a string, but calling the setter yields the following

```
user.test('test')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "--removed--", line 35, in exec_expr
    exec code in self.namespace, self.globs
  File "<web>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Any help pointing out what I'm missing would be greatly appreciated.

PS.  Using SQLAlchemy version 0.9.1

Comment: May or not be relevant, but this problem is coming up while trying to refactor the project from SQLAlchemy 0.5 to 0.9 and python 2.5 to 2.7.  Prior, the get/set was established with a synonym, but it appears the usage of synonym changed in SQLAlchemy 0.7

Comment: Where are you actually seeing this error?  This looks like an error in `Pylons.weberror` hiding the error from `SQLAlchemy`.

Comment: Correct, the error is coming from the Pylons debugger.  There is no SQLAlchemy error being generated as far as I can tell.

Comment: What is `user.test`?  My bet is that is returning you a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original model was using the Classic Mapping style.  Refactoring the model to use the Declarative Mapping style fixed the problem.  I guess hybrid properties only work when the class is using the Declarative base.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't looked deeply enough in to the SQLAlchemy code to say definitively that this is the problem, but my bet is that you are using properties incorrectly.  `set_password` should just be called `password`.  I bet it will fix your problem, but even if it doesn't, you still need to do it that way.  [See this example.](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/orm/extensions/hybrid.html#defining-setters)

You'll see a related error using the builtin `@property` decorator.  Remember, a decorator is just shorthand for assigning the result of a function that takes and returns a callable to the label of the decorated function in the local namespace.  What you are doing here is creating 1 callable and assigning it to `password`, then creating a new callable that wraps the `password` callable and assigning it to `set_password`.  You mention in a comment that it works in an older version of SQLAlchemy.  My bet is that they switched from modifying the wrapped callable object when using `my_var.setter` to returning a new instance.  If you were to use `set_password`, it would most likely work as you expect `password` to work.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but it didn't change anything.

Answer (score 1):

The reason that this did not work is (I suspect) because you were testing the property as if it was a method. From your test code: `user.test()` (I assume that in some version of your code `password` was called `test`.

If you do `user.password('changeme')` then it will not work because user.password is not a method. Instead it should be: `user.password = 'changeme'`

I think it is likely that switching to the Declarative Base was just a coincidence.

Answer (score 0):

I just want to put it here for anyone who might be interested...
I also got this issue when trying to create a password in Airflow.  It seems like a compatibility issue of the sqlalchemy version in Airflow.  I installed this and it solved the issue: pip install 'sqlalchemy<1.2'